Charts have extra padding when printed
I have a page with several charts made with AmCharts4 and I'm setting their height through CSS:
@media print {
    #year-month-chart,
    #cosphi-chart,
    #power-line-chart,
    #yearly-slots-chart 
    {
        height: 230px !important;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 1;
    }
}

Here an example of one chart instantiated:
HTML:
<div id="cosphi-chart"></div>

JS:
var chart = am4core.create("cosphi-chart", am4charts.XYChart);

This is how they look with media emulation set to printer:

But when I print on PDF the charts look weird:

Any idea about this? I already printed AmCharts4 charts but never had this issue.
EDIT: adding some visual debugging:
HTML:
<div style="background-color: yellow;">
        <h3 style="background-color: cyan;" class="text-center">Cosφ</h3>
        <div id="cosphi-chart"></div>
    </div>

Emulator (browser):

PDF:


I was able to improve, I had zoom 80% on the browser. Setting it to 100% has diminished the margin inside the yellow area, but not completely.
